# Can I copy the list of HTTP requests made by a web page out of Firebug’s Net panel?

Tags: http, firefox, testing, firebug

In the Firebug Net panel, you can get a list of all HTTP requests made for the current page.

- http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Is there a way copy this list as text, so that I can paste it somewhere else for my own records? I’m doing some optimisation work, and it’d be really handy to save the requests made for pages before I optimise, so that I can check what effect my optimisation has.

Alternatively, are there any other tools that would give me the same file information (i.e. URL of file requested, size of file — I don’t need the timeline stuff that Firebug’s Net panel does) as Firebug, in text format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) provides a list of HTTP requests made by a web page, and lets you copy the list out as text.

It doesn’t provide the nice breakdowns that Firebug does (e.g. CSS, images, etc.), but the data is there.

Answer (score 5):

FireBug [NetExport](http://getfirebug.com/releases/extensions.html#netexport) extension is what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks grand, although it does seem to export a very full and detailed JSON represenation of the Net panel. If you’re just looking for a couple of columns, you’ll need to do a bit more work to extract just that.

Comment: Thanks for this, you've finally helped me find something better than mozilla archive format.

Answer (score 2):

[LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) will also do this, try the generator tab for a concise list of the requests.