# List All Loaded Files on Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

I'm wondering if it's possible to list all loaded files from a website in Google Chrome (or FireFox). I know I can just go to Developer Tools -> Network, but I mean a nice list that I can use later on to download them all easily (via a script or something). I'm looking to list them like this, for example:

```
http://exmaple.com/test.css
http://exmaple.com/style.css
http://exmaple.com/no.js
http://exmaple.com/website.js
http://exmaple.com/images/web.png
```

Any ideas on how to list each file loaded for a website in Google Chrome or FireFox?

Comment: For Firebug:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941620/can-i-copy-the-list-of-http-requests-made-by-a-web-page-out-of-firebugs-net-pan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin call httpfox. i think its for FireFox tho.

[HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/httpfox/)

Answer (score 0):

I would create some kind of loop that would go through a directory and stop when it has reached the last file in the directory. In this case you would have to use PHP because this is server side. Here is how you would create a PHP file scan: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Furthermore, if you look at the example there is a while loop taking place. It is in this loop I would create a new link ever time the scan discovers a new file such as:

```
<?php 
$dir = "/"
while{ ?> <a href="http://example.com<?php echo $dir . echo $filename ?>">
PHP ECHO DIR AND FILENAME</a>
```